# Listing of running Java applications on linux

Tags: java, linux

Do you guys have some script or GUI tool that would give you nice and transparent listing of running java applications ? I'm using $ps ouput that I grep through for "java" keyword, but usually I'm running eclipse, tomcat, nexus, database IDE and a few others, all of them with many parameters and I'm spending too much time searching through that $ps output. I'm tired of it. Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `jps` - it comes with recent jdks.

Comment: thank you, I wasn't aware of jps, that's much better then grepping $ps output.

Answer (score 1):

I think jvisualvm or jconsole are doing what you expect. These are GUI based and come with recent JVM's as well.

Comment: I meant an overall survey of running applications, rather then profiling processes. It's overkill for what I want.

Comment: They come in handy from time to time and you can have a lot of fun with the JMX view, like setting loglevels on the fly (w/o restarting). If you just need the process list, jps is your thing.

Comment: I tried JMX a year ago and then let my boss check the results in visualVM without him telling me to do so...despite it there was no bonus on my salary cheque :-)

Comment: Well, there was a financial crisis last year, do not give up on educating your bosses (respectfully, of course ;-).